# Populate treetableview from database using FXCollections.observableArrayList()

Tags: javafx, treetableview

I have an expense report query that produces field totals for each day (designated as column “root” as a 1) and dropdown detail for that day (designated as column “root” as a 2).  I can directly fill a table view no problem and can directly fill a treetableview without using `FXCollections.observableArrayList()`.  The problem is I need to use the `FXCollections.observableArrayList()` since I will be using `rowchecker()` and `cellchecker()` that use `cellFactory` callbacks to check cell value and either change the background of the specific cell OR change the background of the entire row which works when filling a tableview.  This is my goal:
Fill a treetableview from database result set; Hide parent and fill treetableview with `“root” = 1` with `“root” = 2` for each date; change background color of cell/row based on cell value.

```
package TreeTableView;
import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import com.jfoenix.controls.RecursiveTreeItem;

import com.jfoenix.controls.datamodels.treetable.RecursiveTreeObject;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeTableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeTableView;
import javafx.util.Callback;
    public class FXMLDocument implements Initializable{

    Connection conn = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    PreparedStatement pst = null;
    Integer idjobs = 286; //temp
    Integer idjobs_by = 6; //temp
    Integer loginID = 4;

    @FXML
    private TreeTableView<ER_Report> tableview;
    ObservableList<ER_Report> ER_report = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    @FXML
    private TreeTableColumn<ER_Report, Number> col1;

    @FXML
    private TreeTableColumn<ER_Report, String> col2;

    @FXML
    private TreeTableColumn<ER_Report, String> col3;

    @FXML
    private TreeTableColumn<ER_Report, String> col4;

    TreeItem<ER_Report> root;

    public void dataset() {         
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM expensereport_total_withlist where job = '" + idjobs + "' and jobby = '" + idjobs_by + "' and employee  = '" + loginID + "' "
                + "order by newSort, root";
        try {
            pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            rs = pst.executeQuery();
            while(rs.next()) {
                DecimalFormat df2 = new DecimalFormat("###0.00");
                DecimalFormat df3 = new DecimalFormat("###0.000");

            Integer c_rootI = 0;
            Date c_Date;
            Integer c_WorkedDayI = 0;
            String c_MealsS = "";
            String c_AirfareS = "";

    c_rootI = rs.getInt("root");
    String c_rootS = c_rootI.toString();
    c_Date = rs.getDate("newSort");
    String c_DateS = c_Date.toString();
    c_WorkedDayI = rs.getInt("workedDay");
    String c_WorkedDayS = c_WorkedDayI.toString();
    Double c_MealsD = rs.getDouble("Meals");
           if(c_MealsD > 0) {
               c_MealsS = "$ " + df2.format(c_MealsD) ;
           }    
    Double c_airD = rs.getDouble("Meals");
        if(c_airD > 0) {
            c_AirfareS = "$ " + df2.format(c_airD) ;
               }

        ER_report.add(new ER_Report(c_rootI, c_DateS,c_MealsS,c_AirfareS));     
            }
            final TreeItem<ER_Report> root = new RecursiveTreeItem<ER_Report>(ER_report, RecursiveTreeObject::getChildren);         


            col1.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<TreeTableColumn.CellDataFeatures<ER_Report, Number>, ObservableValue<Number>>() {               
                @Override
                public ObservableValue<Number> call(TreeTableColumn.CellDataFeatures<ER_Report, Number> param) {
                    return param.getValue().getValue().rootProperty;
                }
            });             
            col2.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<TreeTableColumn.CellDataFeatures<ER_Report, String>, ObservableValue<String>>() {               
                @Override
                public ObservableValue<String> call(TreeTableColumn.CellDataFeatures<ER_Report, String> param) {
                    return param.getValue().getValue().newDateProperty;
                }
            });
            col3.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<TreeTableColumn.CellDataFeatures<ER_Report, String>, ObservableValue<String>>() {               
                @Override
                public ObservableValue<String> call(TreeTableColumn.CellDataFeatures<ER_Report, String> param) {
                    return param.getValue().getValue().mealsProperty;
                }
            });
            col4.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<TreeTableColumn.CellDataFeatures<ER_Report, String>, ObservableValue<String>>() {               
                @Override
                public ObservableValue<String> call(TreeTableColumn.CellDataFeatures<ER_Report, String> param) {
                    return param.getValue().getValue().airProperty;
                }
            });


            root.getChildren().setAll(root);
            tableview.setRoot(root);            
    }catch(Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
    }
        root = new TreeItem<>(new ER_Report(0, "Name", "None", "None"));
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
        conn = connector.ConnectDb();

        idjobs = 286; //temp
        idjobs_by = 6; //temp
        dataset();
    }

    class ER_Report extends RecursiveTreeObject<ER_Report>{ 
        SimpleIntegerProperty rootProperty;
        SimpleStringProperty newDateProperty;
        SimpleStringProperty mealsProperty;
        SimpleStringProperty airProperty;

        public ER_Report(Integer root, String newDate, String meals, String air) {
            this.rootProperty = new SimpleIntegerProperty(root);
            this.newDateProperty = new SimpleStringProperty(newDate);
            this.mealsProperty = new SimpleStringProperty(meals);
            this.airProperty = new SimpleStringProperty(air);
        }

        /**
         * @return the rootProperty
         */
        public SimpleIntegerProperty getRootProperty() {
            return rootProperty;
        }

        /**
         * @param rootProperty the rootProperty to set
         */
        public void setRootProperty(SimpleIntegerProperty rootProperty) {
            this.rootProperty = rootProperty;
        }

        /**
         * @return the newDateProperty
         */
        public SimpleStringProperty getNewDateProperty() {
            return newDateProperty;
        }

        /**
         * @param newDateProperty the newDateProperty to set
         */
        public void setNewDateProperty(SimpleStringProperty newDateProperty) {
            this.newDateProperty = newDateProperty;
        }

        /**
         * @return the mealsProperty
         */
        public SimpleStringProperty getMealsProperty() {
            return mealsProperty;
        }

        /**
         * @param mealsProperty the mealsProperty to set
         */
        public void setMealsProperty(SimpleStringProperty mealsProperty) {
            this.mealsProperty = mealsProperty;
        }

        /**
         * @return the airProperty
         */
        public SimpleStringProperty getAirProperty() {
            return airProperty;
        }

        /**
         * @param airProperty the airProperty to set
         */
        public void setAirProperty(SimpleStringProperty airProperty) {
            this.airProperty = airProperty;
        }


    }
}
```

Next is the result of the query

```
newSort root    Meals   Airfare
6/22/2018   1   94.16   756.46
6/22/2018   2   NULL    756.46
6/22/2018   2   38.53   NULL
6/22/2018   2   55.63   NULL
6/27/2018   1   6.92    NULL
6/27/2018   2   3.63    NULL
6/27/2018   2   3.29    NULL
6/29/2018   1   NULL    698.9
6/29/2018   2   NULL    698.9
```

This is the rowchecker I am using.  I currently don't have the column it will be looking at included in the result set but you can see the code I will be using.

```
 public void rowchecker() {
        Callback<TableColumn<ExpenseReportTable, Integer>, TableCell<ExpenseReportTable, Integer>> cellFactory
        = new Callback<TableColumn<ExpenseReportTable, Integer>, TableCell<ExpenseReportTable, Integer>>() {
public TableCell call(TableColumn p) {
    TableCell cell = new TableCell<ExpenseReportTable, Integer>() {
        @Override
        public void updateItem(Integer item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            if (!empty) {
                  TableRow ttr = getTableRow();
                  if (item == null || empty){
                      setText(null);
                      ttr.setStyle("");
                      setStyle("");
                  } else {
                      ttr.setStyle(item.doubleValue() > 0 
                              ? "-fx-background-color:lightgreen"
                              : "-fx-background-color:#FFE793");
                      setText(item.toString());
                      setStyle(item.doubleValue() > 0 
                              ? "-fx-background-color:green"
                              : "-fx-background-color:lightgreen");
                  }
            } else {
                setText(null);
            }
        }

        private String getString() {
            return getItem() == null ? "" : getItem().toString();
        }
    };

    return cell;
}
};
col_NonWorkedDate.setCellFactory(cellFactory);

    }
```

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and act accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure it out where it works as I want.  Below is the code.

```
package TreeTableView;
import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectWrapper;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeTableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeTableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeTableRow;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeTableView;
import javafx.util.Callback;

public class FXMLDocument implements Initializable{
    Connection conn = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    PreparedStatement pst = null;
    Integer idjobs;
    Integer idjobs_by;
    Integer loginID;

    @FXML
    private TreeTableView<ERItems> tableview;
    TreeItem root = new TreeItem<>("rootxxx");

    @FXML
    private TreeTableColumn<ERItems, Integer> col1;

    @FXML
    private TreeTableColumn<ERItems, String> col2;

    @FXML
    private TreeTableColumn<ERItems, String> col3;

    @FXML
    private TreeTableColumn<ERItems, String> col4;


    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        conn = connector.ConnectDb();           
        idjobs = 286; 
        idjobs_by = 6; 
        loginID = 4;

        dataset2();     

        tableview.setEditable(true);

            Platform.runLater(() -> {

            col2.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> {
            if (cellData.getValue().getValue()instanceof ERItems) {
                return new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper(cellData.getValue().getValue().getCol_date());
            }
            return new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper(cellData.getValue().getValue());
        });

            col3.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> {
            if (cellData.getValue().getValue()instanceof ERItems) {
                return new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper(cellData.getValue().getValue().getCol_meals());
            }
            return new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper(cellData.getValue().getValue());
        });    

            col1.setMinWidth(0);
            col1.setMaxWidth(0);
            col1.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> {
            if (cellData.getValue().getValue()instanceof ERItems) {
                return new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper(cellData.getValue().getValue().getCol_workedDay());
            }
            return new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper(cellData.getValue().getValue());
        }); 

            col4.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> {
            if (cellData.getValue().getValue()instanceof ERItems) {
                return new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper(cellData.getValue().getValue().getCol_air());
            }
            return new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper(cellData.getValue().getValue());
        }); 

            tableview.setTreeColumn(col2);
            tableview.setRoot(root);                
            tableview.setShowRoot(false);
            rowchecker();
            root.setExpanded(true);
        });   
}

    public void dataset2() {
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM expensereport_total_withlist where job = '" + idjobs + "' and jobby = '" + idjobs_by + "' and employee  = '" + loginID + "' "
                + "order by newSort, root";
        try {
            pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            rs = pst.executeQuery();                

            String currentDate = null;
            String currentRoot = null;
            TreeItem<String> tiDate = null;
            TreeItem<String> tiRoot = null;  
            TreeItem<ERItems> nodeRoot = null;
            TreeItem<ERItems> nodeChild = null;
            ReliantER tiReliantER = null;
            TreeItem<ReliantER> nodeItem = null;
            Integer inputRowCounter = 0;

            while(rs.next()) {              
                DecimalFormat df2 = new DecimalFormat("###0.00");
                DecimalFormat df3 = new DecimalFormat("###0.000");                  
                Integer c_rootI = 0;
                Date c_Date;
                Integer c_WorkedDayI = 0;
                String c_MealsS = "";
                String c_AirfareS = "";

                c_rootI = rs.getInt("root");
                String c_rootS = c_rootI.toString();
                c_Date = rs.getDate("newSort");
                String c_DateS = c_Date.toString();
                c_WorkedDayI = rs.getInt("workedDay");
                String c_WorkedDayS = c_WorkedDayI.toString();
                Double c_MealsD = rs.getDouble("Meals");
                   if(c_MealsD > 0) {
                       c_MealsS = "$ " + df2.format(c_MealsD) ;
                   }    

                Double c_airD = rs.getDouble("Airfare");
                    if(c_airD > 0) {
                        c_AirfareS = "$ " + df2.format(c_airD) ;
                   }    

                    if (c_rootI == 1 ){
                        nodeRoot = new TreeItem<> (new ERItems(rs.getInt("workedDay"), c_DateS, c_MealsS, c_AirfareS)); 
                        root.getChildren().add(nodeRoot);
                    }else{
                        if(rs.getInt("receiptActive") == 1) {
                            nodeChild = new TreeItem<> (new ERItems(rs.getInt("workedDay"), c_DateS, c_MealsS, c_AirfareS));    
                            nodeRoot.getChildren().add(nodeChild);
                        }
                    }
                        inputRowCounter = inputRowCounter + 1;        
                }   
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Alert a1 = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
                a1.showAndWait();
            }                       
    }        


public void rowchecker() {
    Callback<TreeTableColumn<ERItems, Integer>, TreeTableCell<ERItems, Integer>> cellFactory
    = new Callback<TreeTableColumn<ERItems, Integer>, TreeTableCell<ERItems, Integer>>() {
        public TreeTableCell call(TreeTableColumn p) {
            TreeTableCell cell = new TreeTableCell<ERItems, Integer>() {
                @Override
                public void updateItem(Integer item, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);
                    if (!empty) {
                          TreeTableRow ttr = getTreeTableRow();
                          if (item == null || empty){
                              setText(null);
                              ttr.setStyle("");
                              setStyle("");
                          } else {
                             ttr.setStyle(item.doubleValue() > 0 
                                      ? ""
                                      : "-fx-background-color:#FFE793");
                              setText(item.toString());
                           //   setStyle(item.doubleValue() > 0 
                           //           ? "-fx-background-color:green"
                           //           : "-fx-background-color:lightgreen");
                          }
                    } else {
                        setText(null);
                    }
                }       
                private String getString() {
                    return getItem() == null ? "" : getItem().toString();
                }
            };      
            return cell;
        }
    };
    col1.setCellFactory(cellFactory);   
    }

public static class ERItems {

    private final SimpleIntegerProperty col_workedDay;
    private final SimpleStringProperty col_meals;
    private final SimpleStringProperty col_air;
    private final SimpleStringProperty col_date;



    private ERItems(Integer col_workedDay, String col_date, String col_meals, String col_air) {
        this.col_workedDay = new SimpleIntegerProperty(col_workedDay);
        this.col_date = new SimpleStringProperty(col_date);
        this.col_meals = new SimpleStringProperty(col_meals);
        this.col_air = new SimpleStringProperty(col_air);
    }


    public String getCol_meals() {
        return col_meals.get();
    }

    public String getCol_air() {
        return col_air.get();
    }

    public String getCol_date() {
        return col_date.get();
    }


    public Integer getCol_workedDay() {
        return col_workedDay.get();
    }

}       

}
```

Now it gives me the Treetable with parent rows of daily totals and child rows of individual receipts for that day.  Then the rowchecker looks at col1 to see if it's a day the employee logged work hours and highlight the row(s) if they have expenses for the day.

[Treetableview result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NO2rG.png)